# Is there any add on for Thymeleaf for Spring Roo?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo, thymeleaf

Now I develop Spring project with Spring Roo, I want to use Thymeleaf instead of default .japx page. How to generate Thymeleaf in Spring Roo.

Comment: @Kyaw Sorry to chip in so long after this was asked but did you mean .japx? Couldn't find any reference to this, did you perhaps mean JSPs or something else?

Answer (score 3):

As of the current Spring Roo version 1.2.3 there is no support (that I could find after days of roaming the internet).

I would switch to Thymeleaf immediately when such an addon would become available! If you find such an addon, do share!